# Mapping headers via File.readlines

Tags: ruby, csv

This works great for me.

```
lines = CSV.readlines("log.csv")
a = lines.map{|s| {timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3]} }
puts a
```

Amended as clearer.

```
lines = CSV.readlines("log.csv").map do |s|
  s = {timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3]}
end
puts a
```

But I am looking at doing additional filtering using grep, and this fails miserably.

```
1.9.3-p448 :129 > lines = File.readlines("log.csv").grep(/watch\?v=/)
 => [] 
1.9.3-p448 :134 > lines.map{|s| {timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3]} }
=> [{:timestamp=>"\"", :url=>"2", :ip=>" "}, {:timestamp=>"\"", :url=>"2", :ip=>" "}
```

**Solution**

```
a = File.readlines('log.csv').grep(/watch\?v=/).map do |s|
  s = s.parse_csv;
  { timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3] }
end
puts a
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CSV` class adds the `parse_csv` method to `String`. So you can parse the file records one at a time like this

```
lines = File.readlines("log.csv").grep(/watch\?v=/)
a = lines.map{ |s| s = s.parse_csv; {timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3]} }
puts a
```

or, preferably

```
a = File.readlines('log.csv').grep(/watch\?v=/).map do |s|
  s = s.parse_csv;
  { timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3] }
end
puts a
```

Comment: Got both examples working.  The 2nd example you provided was very clear.  Thanks.